# If you had a Tumblr rant/stand-up comedy crossover, what would be the best word to describe such manner of delivery?

Tags: single-word-requests

By *Tumblr rant*, I mean some sort of monologue, sometimes long,
and mostly having an angry or annoyed mood. It usually has a message,
but may be overloaded by emotions and considered complaining.

By *stand-up comedy*, I mean something more lighthearted and less
condensed, something that may sound witty but which is still more focused
on maintaining the light mood than on delivering a complete message.

And as a crossover of both, we could have any sort of delivery, from
a TED-like speech to a burst of angry sentences to anything in between;
something free of any form constraints, something not bound to be pleasing
or degrading, boring or funny (hence no *lecture* or *joke*). The only
expectations of this format are that a certain insightful message should
be present.

Obviously I’m going for a wide range of delivery types, so no single
best word describing them all might exist. But please do share the terms
that you’d use to describe such kind of post or speech.

Originally I was thinking that *rant* was a good term enough, but googling
and reading the Quora answers on the topic led me to me believe that it
has a strongly negative connotation, to the point that *ranting* could
be viewed as synonymous to *complaining*. And although I want the term
to describe complaints as well, I’d like to go beyond just them.

Still, *rant* is a good reference to how the word I’m after might be
used, for example in sentences like:

> Have you read that huge **ᴛᴇʀᴍ** John has posted on Instagram?

For the same reason, I’m looking for a single-word term, because
anything compound would sound too complex and formal in such a context.

Comment: I like the word `rant`. I don't think it implies complaining. Rather, to me, it implies the pressured-speech of a person who has too much to say and not enough words with which to say it. Dennis Miller was an expert on the comedic rant. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wL9dXgUkbw&ab_channel=dovenol

Comment: Difficult. I like *spiel* but its meaning is not wide enough to embrace your specification.

Comment: I'm hearing a *meltdown*.